# What Browsers Allow Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest From Local Files?

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest, local, cross-domain

I know Internet Explorer 8 allows cross-domain XHR from LOCAL files, but what about other browsers? I'd like to know about what versions/OS this will work on (if any) for each of the major 5 browsers. Please include any workarounds like Chrome's `--disable-web-security` flag.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are to upload local file to server, you may want to use HTML5 File API and XHR to send the blob to server.

Answer (score 1):

well here is a nice blog abt  cross domain requests:  http://caffeinelab.net/2011/02/08/cross-domain-requests-state-of-the-browsers/

> IE provides access control to do cross-domain requests. Now the bad
>   news: as usual, IE can’t do like the others and they have their own
>   non-standard way to provide it.
>
> Instead of a regular XMLHttpRequest, you need to do a XDomainRequest!
>   Moreover, it works only for public pages, not for authenticated pages.
>   So if you need to send he cookies and you want your application to
>   work in IE, you’re pretty much screwed.

and here is how you do it in FFX: http://dirolf.com/2007/06/enabling-cross-domain-ajax-in-firefox.html

Not sure about safari, but Chrome has a command line switch for this:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Keep in mind when you enable this you are risking your security when you visit other sites. so be careful

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari you can enable the Develop menu (Safari → Preferences → Advanced → Show Develop menu in menu bar). There you can disable cross-origin restrictions (Develop → Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions).