# Web Audio API localfiles?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/......../Web/Sykbox/undefined. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

I know is because the Same-origin policy, but I was wondering if there is a method for load localfiles.
This is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sykbox </title>
    <link href="styles/syk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "loadDog();" value = "Play" />
    <script src = "scripts/sykAudio.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var audioCtx;
var bufferDog;
var url = "../data/TaktofWind.ogg";

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init() {
     try {
           window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
            audioCtx = new AudioContext();
     }
     catch(e) {
            alert("Web Audio API no es soportado por tu navegador");
      }
 }
 function loadDog(url) {
               var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
               request.open('GET', url, true);
               request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
               request.onload = function() {
               audioCtx.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) { bufferDog = buffer;                         
                                                               playSound(bufferDog); }, function(error) {            
                                                               console.error("decodeAudioData error", error); } );
               };
               request.send();
    }
    function playSound(buffer) {
                var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
                source.buffer = buffer;
                source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                source.start(0);
    }
```

Comment: If you have Python installed, you can use it to [start a simple HTTP server](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python).

Comment: This has nothing to do with WebAudio. This is XHR policies on local files. This will get into CSP and other browser based security policies for access local files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141280/what-browsers-allow-cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-from-local-files